# What's the type error in this expression `snd (True, [2,[5]])`?

Tags: haskell

When I evaluate the expression,

```
snd (True, [2,[5]])
```

the compiler says:

```
 • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [a]
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a. (Num a, Num [a]) => [[a]]
```

How can I solve it ? For me, `snd` should work on any tuple type based on its signature, but perhaps that is not the case.

Comment: while (as often with GHC and numeric types) the error is needlessly confusing, may I ask you what type you think `[2, [5]]` actually is? Bearing in mind that a list in Haskell must have all its elements be the same type.

Comment: Of course, even that expression doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the expression `[2,[5]]`. It's invalid for the same reason that `['x',True]` is invalid: in Haskell, all elements of a list must be of the same type.

The reason you got a cryptic error message from `[2,[5]]` instead of the simple error message `Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘Bool’` that `['x',True]` yields is that numeric literals in Haskell are polymorphic, so if you had a *really* weird (and probably unlawful) `Num` instance in scope, then it would be technically possible to create and use such a type; it just almost certainly wouldn't do what you wanted.

Just for fun, here's a case where what you wrote would be valid (and the instances are even lawful):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules, FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances #-}

instance Num () where
    _ + _ = ()
    _ * _ = ()
    abs _ = ()
    signum _ = ()
    fromInteger _ = ()
    _ - _ = ()

instance Num [()] where
    (+) = (++)
    (*) = (*>)
    abs = id
    signum _ = [()]
    fromInteger x
        | x >= 0 = replicate (fromInteger x) ()
        | otherwise = error "if Natural can bottom here, so can this"
    xs - [] = xs
    (_:xs) - (_:ys) = xs - ys
    [] - (_:_) = error "if Natural can bottom here, so can this"

main :: IO ()
main = print $ snd (True, [2,[5]])
```

It prints `[[(),()],[()]]`.